# column names to matrix format in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following dataset:

```
       A..B A..C B..C
value  2    5    9
```

and I would like to break it in a way such as I get the following output:

```
  A  B  C

A 1  2  5

B 2  1  9

C 5  9  1
```

in ideas on how can I do this in r?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should be a 9. I just corrected it. thanks

Comment: In case it is sorted maybe: `m <- matrix(1, 3, 3); m[lower.tri(m)] <- c(2,5,9); m[upper.tri(m)]  <-  t(m)[upper.tri(m)]`

Comment: There's also [`vec2symmat()`](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/reference/vec2symmat.html) from [my SOfun package](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/index.html). You'd have to add the names in, but to get the matrix, you could do `library(SOfun); vec2symmat(unlist(df))`. The function basically boils down to @GKi's suggestion, but with some additional feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the base R code below

```
dn <- strsplit(names(df), "..", fixed = TRUE)
mat <- `dimnames<-`(diag(rep(1, ncol(df))), replicate(2, list(unique(unlist(dn)))))
inds <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dn, function(x) rbind(x, rev(x))))
mat[inds] <- rep(unlist(df), each = 2)
```

or

```
dn <- strsplit(names(df), "..", fixed = TRUE)
mat <- `dimnames<-`(diag(rep(1, ncol(df))), replicate(2, list(unique(unlist(dn)))))
for (k in seq_along(dn)) {
  mat[do.call(cbind, as.list(dn[[k]]))] <- df[, k]
}
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[lower.tri(mat)]
```

such that

```
> mat
  A B C
A 1 2 5
B 2 1 9
C 5 9 1
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A..B = 2L, A..C = 5L, B..C = 9L), class = "data.frame", row.names = "value")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  separate(name, into = c('name1', 'name2')) %>% 
  complete(name1 = LETTERS[1:3], name2 = LETTERS[1:3],
      fill = list(value = 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name2, values_from = value) %>% 
  column_to_rownames('name1') %>%
  as.matrix %>% 
  {. + t(.)} %>%
   `diag<-`(., 1)
#   A B C
#A 1 2 5
#B 2 1 9
#C 5 9 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A..B = 2L, A..C = 5L, B..C = 9L),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = "value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option that uses matrix indexing to fill in the values:

```
library(splitstackshape)
# stack your dataset and split the names into two columns
x <- cSplit(stack(df), "ind", "..")
# ij is going to be your index of row and column combinations
ij <- as.matrix(x[, 2:3])
u <- unique(c(ij))

# initialze a matrix of 1s
m <- matrix(1, nrow = length(u), ncol = length(u),
            dimnames = list(u, u))

# replace the relevant indices with values
m[rbind(ij, ij[, 2:1])] <- x$values
m
#   A B C
# A 1 2 5
# B 2 1 9
# C 5 9 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `strsplit` to get the names, use `unique` to get all levels and create a `matrix` initialized with `1L` and the size of the levels. Then you can fill up the matrix by using the names to find the position of the values.

```
i <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(x), "..", TRUE))
u <- unique(as.vector(i))
m <- matrix(1L, length(u), length(u), dimnames = list(u, u))
m[rbind(i, i[,2:1])] <- unlist(x)
#m[rbind(i, i[,2:1])] <- x #Alternative in case of a vector
m
#  A B C
#A 1 2 5
#B 2 1 9
#C 5 9 1
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(A..B = 2L, A..C = 5L, B..C = 9L, row.names = "value")
#x <- c(A..B = 2L, A..C = 5L, B..C = 9L) #Alternative as a vector
```